# Async code returns different value from regular code

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I have a long running function which executes for every object in an Array, and I created a function that will create a Task array of the function results and append them to the objects after completion.
My problem is that when I tried to make this function Async, all the Task.Result(s) in the Task Array ended up null...

This is my Async code, which produces the unwanted nulls:

```
public async void Update() {
        var taskArray = new Task<FunctionResult>[Data.Count];
        for (var i = 0; i < Data.Count; i++) {
            var currentObject = Data[i];
            taskArray[i] = Task.Run(() => new Function(currentObject));
        }
        var results = await Task.WhenAll(taskArray);
        ...
}
```

With this code, "results" contains only nulls, and also finishes the unrealistically fast as if it doesn't execute the function fully...

This normal code does work:

```
public void Update() {
            var taskArray = new Task<FunctionResult>[Data.Count];
            for (var i = 0; i < Data.Count; i++) {
                var currentObject = Data[i];
                taskArray[i] = Task.Run(() => new Function(currentObject));
            }
            Task.WaitAll(taskArray);
            var results = taskArray.Select(s => s.Result).ToArray();
            ...
    }
```

My question is why is it? In my understanding both versions should complete the exact same task up to the point where I assign "results", so why does the regular version produce the correct result and the Async version doesn't?

Comment: I think you'll want `Task.WaitAll`, not `Task.WhenAll`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen `Task.WaitAll()` returns `void` so is not awaitable, which is why I use it in the Non-Async function.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is hidden in the declaration of `public async void Update()`. You simply can't await this method properly because the caller doesn't have a `Task` to await.
You should declare it as `public async Task Update()`, and wait the task properly in the place where `Update()` method is called.

Comment: it does make sense... I guess I just wanted to avoid using a `Task` in the place `Update` was called as well...

Comment: You can use the `.Wait()` method in the place where `Update()` was called. But in that case, you will block the current thread (as it is in the Non-Async variant)